# How do I use %SYSTEMROOT% in VBS?

Tags: vbscript

I use this code to download a link and I want to save a file in `%SystemRoot%\system32` but when replace **`C:\`** with **`%SystemRoot%`**, the VBS can't run.

```
function download(sFileURL, sLocation)

    'create xmlhttp object
    Set objXMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

    'get the remote file
    objXMLHTTP.open "GET", sFileURL, false

    'send the request
    objXMLHTTP.send()

    'wait until the data has downloaded successfully
    do until objXMLHTTP.Status = 200 :  wcript.sleep(1000) :  loop

    'if the data has downloaded sucessfully
    If objXMLHTTP.Status = 200 Then

            'create binary stream object
        Set objADOStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        objADOStream.Open

            'adTypeBinary
        objADOStream.Type = 1
        objADOStream.Write objXMLHTTP.ResponseBody

            'Set the stream position to the start
        objADOStream.Position = 0    

            'create file system object to allow the script to check for an existing file
            Set objFSO = Createobject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

            'check if the file exists, if it exists then delete it
        If objFSO.Fileexists(sLocation) Then objFSO.DeleteFile sLocation

            'destroy file system object
        Set objFSO = Nothing

            'save the ado stream to a file
        objADOStream.SaveToFile sLocation

            'close the ado stream
        objADOStream.Close

        'destroy the ado stream object
        Set objADOStream = Nothing

    'end object downloaded successfully
    End if

    'destroy xml http object
    Set objXMLHTTP = Nothing

End function

download "http://remote-location-of-file", "C:\name-of-file-and-extension"

download "http://demo.com/test.gif", "C:\test.gif" **OK**  
download "http://demo.com/test.gif", "%SystemRoot%\system32\test.gif"  **Faild**
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to read environment variable in a **VBS** variable. Something like:

```
Dim mySystemRoot
Dim myPath
Dim wshShell
Set wshShell = CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
mySystemRoot = wshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings( "%SystemRoot%" )
wshShell = Nothing
download "http://demo.com/test.gif", myPath & "\test.gif"
```

Then use `mySystemRoot` variable to form your file path.

Comment: i add your code after **End function** but I guess I do not write the correct address of the patch.  
http://www.uploadimage.in/di-N24L.gif

Comment: The error message appears again
**Error: Object variable not set: 'wshShell'**
Line 59 (wshShell = Nothing)

Comment: @Amirreza: add this to the top: `Dim wshShell`. You should follow a tutorial on basic VBScript to understand how variables and strings work.

Comment: Thanks i could edit and use this code.
how can add a command that if script not found link, doesn't show error?